# Loading PostgreSQL table to in-memory cache for x-dimensional lookup in python/django

Tags: python, postgresql, caching, memory

I'm working on a Python/Django webapp...and I'm really just digging into Python for the first time (typically I'm a .NET/core stack dev)...currently running PostgreSQL on the backend.  I have about 9-10 simple (2 dimensional) lookup tables that will be hit very, very often in real time, that I would like to cache them in memory.

Ideally, I'd like to do this with Postgres itself, but it may be that another data engine and/or some other library will be suited to help with this (I'm not super familiar with Python libraries).

Goals would be:

1. Lookups are handled in memory (data footprint will never be "large").
2. Ideally, results could be cached after the first pull (by complete parameter signature) to optimize time, although this is somewhat optional as I'm assuming in-memory lookup would be pretty quick anyway....and
3. Also optional, but ideally, even though the lookup tables are stored separately in the db for importing/human-readability/editing purposes, I would think generating a x-dimensional array for the lookup when loaded into memory would be optimal.   Though there are about 9-10 lookup tables total, there only maybe 10-15 values per table (some smaller) and probably a total of only maybe 15 parameters total for the complete lookup against all tables.   Basically it's 9-10 tables of a modifier for an equation....so given certain values we lookup x/y values in each table, get the value, and add them together.

So I guess I'm looking for a library and/or suitable backend that handles the in-memory loading and caching (again, total size of this footprint in RAM will never be a factor)... and possibly can automatically resolve the x lookup tables into a single in-memory x-dimensional table for efficiency (rather than making 9-10 look-ups seperately)....and caching these results for repeated use when all parameters match a previous query (unless the lookup performs so quickly this is irrelevant).

Lookup tables are not huge...I would say, if I were to write code to break down each x/y value/range and create one giant x-dimensional lookup table by hand, it would probably endup with maybe 15 fields and 150 rows-ish...so we aren't talking very much data....but it will be hit very, very often and I don't want to perform these lookups everytime against the actual DB.

Recommendations for an engine/library suited best for this (with a preference for still being able to use postgresql for the persistent storage) are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special to achieve that: if you use the tables frequently, PostgreSQL will make them stay in cache automatically.

If you need to haye the tables in cache right from the start, use [`pg_prewarm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgprewarm.html). It allows you to explicitly load certain tables into cache and can automatically restore the state of the cache as it was before the last shutdown.

Once the tables are cached, they will only cause I/O when you write to them.

The efficient in-memory data structures you envision sound like a premature micro-optimization to me. I'd bet that these small lookup tables won't cause a performance problem (if you have indexes on all foreign keys).